# Integrating a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, integration

How does $(xJ_0'(x))'+xJ_0(x)=0\implies\int\nolimits_0^1 x J_0(ax)J_0(bx) dx={bJ_0(a)J_0'(b)-aJ_0(b)J_0'(a)\over{a^2-b^2}}?$ Thanks.

Perhaps int by parts? But how do I get the RHS form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(xJ_0'(x))'+xJ_0(x)=0$ also means

$$(xJ_0'(ax))'+axJ_0(ax)=0$$

which can be found by substituting $x\to ax$.

---

**EDIT:** To make the first step more explicit

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x \frac{dJ_0(x)}{dx}\right)+xJ_0(x) = 0 \to \frac{d}{d(ax)}\left(ax \frac{dJ_0(ax)}{d(ax)}\right)+axJ_0(ax) = 0$$

---

Multiplying this by $J_0(bx)$ and integrating gets you:

$$\int_0^1(xJ_0'(ax))'J_0(bx)dx+ a\int_0^1xJ_0(ax)J_0(bx)dx = 0 \; ,$$

and using partial integration on the first term

$$J_0'(a)J_0(b)-b\int_0^1 xJ_0'(ax)J_0'(bx)dx+ a\int_0^1 xJ_0(ax)J_0(bx)dx = 0 \; .$$

Exchanging $a$ and $b$ in this equation, you also have

$$J_0'(b)J_0(a)-a\int_0^1 xJ_0'(ax)J_0'(bx)dx+ b\int_0^1 xJ_0(ax)J_0(bx)dx = 0 \; .$$

Multypling the first equation by $a$ and the second by $b$ and then subtracting both of them gets you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to be unable to get the 1st line result -- change of variable. I get $d/dx [(1/a)x(d/dx (J_0(ax)))]+ axJ_0(ax)=0$? because $d/d(ax)=d/dx\times d/d(ax)$?

Comment: Note that $dJ_0(ax)/d(ax) = J_0'(ax)$.